# Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm'

Tags: django, django-registration

**Django==1.11.2**

**django-registration-redux==1.6**

When I'm trying to reset password (http://localhost:8000/accounts/password/reset/), I occur at a page with headline Django administration, and breadcrumbs below: Home › Password reset. So, this is a part of Django functionality. This may be important, though, I don't know how. But anyway, this is not the functionality of django-registration-redux.

I input an email. And get this:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

In django-registration-redux another name is used. Namely auth_password_reset_confirm.

Well, could you give me a kick here? My settings are below:

**settings.py**

```
INCLUDE_REGISTER_URL = True
INCLUDE_AUTH_URLS = True
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
}
```

Comment: Mentioned [here](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/140)

Comment: Yes, it really helped. Thank you. If you write "Put registration over django.contrib.admin" as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the bug report, `registration` must be earlier in order then admin. Not entirely sure why and apparently it's hard to fix, as this package is maintained by several Django core team members :).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2/quickstart.html#quickstart: `django.contrib.auth` must be in `INSTALLED_APPS`, I suggest adding before `registration` so that the package can override the core

Comment: It will not help. Reason: registration app is should be placed above django.contrib.admin (not only auth). The question is solved. Melvyn helped.